# Area & order-preserving function transformations

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, geometry, functions, polynomials

Consider a bounded function $f(x \in \mathbf{R}) \rightarrow \mathbf{R}$ with bounded support $\left[0,L\right]$ (illustration below).

What type of transformations $g(f(x))$ guarantee that:

1. Area under the curve between $x=0$ and $x=L$ of $g\left(f(x)\right)$ is equal to that of $f(x)$
2. For any pair of $(x_1,x_2)$ points, the **ordering** of $g\left(f(x_1)\right)$ and $g\left(f(x_2)\right)$ is that of  $f(x_1)$ and $f(x_2)$
3. $g\left(f(x)\right)\ge0 \, \forall x$, noting that $f(x)\ge 0$ as well.

For example, what subset of linear transformations $g(f(x)) = A f(x) + B$ satisfy this property? What about non-linear transformations? Any good (algebraically simple) examples of the latter?

[image]

Comment: When you say "area", you're talking about area in $\Bbb R^2$, right? In that case, what exactly do you mean by an "area-preserving transformation of a function", since a function is not a region in $\Bbb R^2$?

Comment: Thanks @GregMartin I mean that the area under the curve for the new function $g(x)$ should be the same as that of $f(x)$

Comment: Maybe take a look at mean preserving spreads to answer 1? (I mean types of transformations that mean preserving spread the distribution)

Comment: Quite a bit clearer, now, thanks ... still one question: when you say the "area under the curve", do you mean only the area bounded by $x=0$ and $x=L$? Or the area bounded by other vertical lines as well. - In the former interpretation, defining $g(x)=Ax+B$ works precisely when $A>0$ and $B$ equals $1-A$ times the area under the curve, for example (as you can show by comparing $\int_0^L f(x)\,dx$ with $\int_0^L (Af(x)+B)\,dx$). There might be additional constraints if you interpret "area under the curve" literally, demanding that the graph of $y=Af(x)+B$ isn't allowed to cross the $x$-axis.

Comment: Oh good point @GregMartin. Yes, $g(x)$ should **not** be allowed to cross the x line (and we assume $f(x)$ does not either). As for "area under the curve", yes, it is only meant for the area between $x=0$ and $x=L$.

Comment: Thanks! but omething still doesn't quite fit for me. When I solve for $B$ in $\int_0^Lf(x)dx = \int_0^L\left(Af(x) + B\right)dx$ I get: $B = \frac{\left(1-A\right)\int_0^Lf(x)dx}{L}$, in other words, $B = \frac{(1-A) \cdot Area}{L}$. How did you end up with no $L$ (or with $L=1$) in your result?

Comment: You're right, I forgot the $1/L$.

Comment: PS: Your question would be a little bit easier to understand if you were consistent on whether you want $g(x)$ or $g(f(x))$.

Comment: Thanks @GregMartin I have updated the OP to reflect that I am asking about $g(f(x))$.